# Выполнять действие при скролле каждые 30px

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Здравствуйте,

Получаем значение скролла и указываем промежуток в котором необходимо выполнить действия:

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if(scroll >= 100 && scroll <=1000) {
}
```

Затем необходимо в указанном промежутке, каждые 30px выполнять какое-либо действие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например дополнительной проверкой:

```js
let lowerScrolledPosition = 0;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  let scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 100 && scroll <= 1000 && lowerScrolledPosition < scroll - 30) {
  lowerScrolledPosition = scroll;
    console.log(lowerScrolledPosition);
  }
});
```

```css
.fake {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fake"></div>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что при разной скорости прокрутки, выполняется разное количество действий

Comment: @ВалерийАликин напишите в вопросе что вы хотите этим добиться - я почти уверен что есть решение оптимальнее.

Answer (score 1):

Почему не использовать scroll? и так уже проверять промежуток
Пример на :[JSFDD Click](https://jsfiddle.net/vuw9ohg3/)

```
var count = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
     console.log(pageYOffset); 
  console.log(count);
  if (pageYOffset > 100 && pageYOffset < 1000) {
    if (pageYOffset - count > 30 ) {
        // ВАШИ ДЕЙСТВИЯ
      count = pageYOffset;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: это да, меня интересует как выполнять действие каждые 30px скролла

Comment: @Валерий Аликин Исправил ответ

Comment: Проблема в том, что при разной скорости прокрутки, выполняется разное количество действий